# CNTK for waveform input?

Tags: nlp, cntk

I want to use Neural Networks to classify periodic signals coming from a sensor.  I've only done image stuff before with CNTK.  I suppose its a bit like NLP in that a continuous waveform in the input -- but in my case it won't be audio, but something else.  Can somebody point me to how I might get started on this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if the following links in the sequential order help ?

https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/Manual_How_to_feed_data.html#Comma-separated-values-(CSV)

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/2199